# Running remotely a batch file from a usb drive, without doing it there

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a vbs file in my USB that runs a bat file in my documents, however, the command window is in the USB's directory, and not in the documents. I understand that the vbs is opening a command prompt *there* and then executing it, but that creates a process in my usb drive, which I want to remove once the vbs file has been executed. is there a way to run a command prompt that is not in the usb?

Comment: Well, why not run it from the desktop using mounted USB directory as a source of the VBS?

Comment: Well. Windows command prompt opens in `%Windir%`, not from the USB.